# Where Clause In Jason Response Array Data

Tags: android, json

I am returning some Array Data in Jason Response in my android application with below code.

```
 JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);
    String[] stocks = new String[jsonArray.length()];
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject obj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

        stocks[i] = obj.getString("name");
        stocks[i] = obj.getString("mobile_numer");
      }
```

What I need to do is to return data against certain `mobile_number` only like regular sql `where mobile_number=$mobile_number` how can achieve this in above

Answer (score 0):

Just request with the mobile number as query-string parameter and then add this value into the `WHERE` clause on the server-side - in order not having to mess around on the client-side.

Comment: is there any way to do this in client-side?